# Regex matches only part of a URL - why?

Tags: java, regex

I am very weak in regex and the regex I am using (found from internet) is only partially solving my problem. I need to  add an anchor tag to a URL from text input using java. Here is my code:

```
String text ="Hi please visit www.google.com";
String reg = "\\b(([\\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\\s()<>]+(?:\\([\\w\\d]+\\)|([^[:punct:]\\s]|/)))";
        String s = text.replaceAll(reg, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
        System.out.println(""+s);
```

The output currently is `Hi please visit <a href='www.google.c'>www.google.c</a>om`. What's wrong with the regex?

I need to parse a text and display a URL entered from text field as hot link in a jsp page. The actual output expected would be

```
Hi please visit <a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>
```

**Edit**

Following regex

```
(http(s)?://)?(www(\.\w+)+[^\s.,"']*)
```

works like a charm in url ending with `.com` but fails in other extensions like `.jsp`.Is there any way for it to work in all sort of extension?

Comment: I'm all for using `regex`, but why are you using them for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java recognises posix expressions ([see javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)), but the syntax is a little different. It looks like this instead:

```
\p{Punct}
```

But I would simplify your regex for a URL to:

```
(?i)(http(s)?://)?((www(\.\w+)+|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\.\d{1,3})[^\s,"']*(?<!\\.))
```

And elaborate it only if you find a test case that breaks it.

As a java line it would be:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?i)(http(s)?://)?((www(\\.\w+)+|(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})[^\\s,\"']*(?<!\\.))", "<a href=\"http$2://$3\">$3</a>");
```

Note the neat capture of the "s" in "https" (if found) that is restored if required.

Comment: thanks..that's an awesome answer.But it does not work if the url is `www.askqology.com/CareWave/login.jsp`.The URL returned would omit .jsp but it is working marvelously in other cases

Comment: @ntstha right! Of course. I have modified the regex so that the URL can't *end* with a dot (if it does, it's considered as punctuation and left as-is). I also added `(?i)` to make the match case-insensitive. See edited answer.

Comment: @ntstha You're welcome :) (And welcome to the dark art of regex!)

Comment: hi sir.Sorry to disturb you again but if i enter Hi this is `Hi please visit www.google.com to solve all your queries` will return `Hi please visit <a style='text-decoration:underline' target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com to solve all your queries">www.google.com to solve all your queries</a>`.Sir please i need your help.I am not good in regex and the regex you provided is already too complex for me to update

Comment: OK fixed it. I changed the `[^.]*` to `(?<!\\.)`, which is a negative look behind for a dot - it means that while the url can *contain* a dot, but it can't *end* in a dot. So it will find just `www.google.com` in `Go to www.google.com.`. The answer has been updated.

Comment: thnks sir for the help. but it is not working in case if the url is `Hi please visit http://66.66.12.34/qa.jsp?qa=367 here it is`. I think it is because `www` is compulsory but i think it would be good if occurence of `www` is made optional but either `http` or `www` is to be present for the link to be valid. So `66.66.12.34/qa.jsp?qa=367` would not be a valid url.

Comment: I've added in the option to have an ip address instead of a host name

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question why the regex doesn't work: It doesn't observe Java's regex syntax rules.

Specifically:

```
[^[:punct:]\s]
```

doesn't work as you expect it to because Java doesn't recognize POSIX shorthands like `[:punct:]`. Instead, it treats that as a nested character class. That again leads to the `^`  becoming illegal in that context, so Java ignores it, leaving you with a character class that matches the same as

```
[:punct\s]
```

which only matches the `c` of `com`, therefore ending your match there.

As for your question of how to find URLs in a block of text, I suggest you read Jan Goyvaert's excellent blog entry [Detecting URLs in a block of text](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/). You'll need to decide yourself how sensitive and how specific you want to make your regex.

For example, the solution proposed at the end of the post would translate to Java as

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(
    "(?imx)\\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\\.|ftp\\.)\n" +
    "(?:\\([-A-Z0-9+&@\\#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\\)|\n" +
    "      [-A-Z0-9+&@\\#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*\n" +
    "(?:\\([-A-Z0-9+&@\\#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\\)|\n" +
    "      [A-Z0-9+&@\\#/%=~_|$])", "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>");
```

Comment: thnks for identifying the problem.But i need solution as well.My regex knowledge is weak for me to solve it myself.

Comment: @ntstha Just manually add the characters within the class `[:punct:]`: `][!'#$()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-`

Comment: thnks sir..would you mind posting the regex in your answer.I did add characters but its giving me pattern syntax exception.I have missed something.